# input type file not showing file chooser

Tags: html, forms, file-upload

I'm trying to create a HTML5 web-form that collects a few fields of data along with a picture file from a device's camera.  It was working fine earlier, but I started messing with the code and now it won't.  I can't figure out why.  The file chooser code is:

```
<dl>
<dt>
<label for="voidedCheck">Voided Check:</label>
</dt>
<dd><br><input type="file" style="font-size:16px; height:25px;width:240px" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="voidedCheck" name="voidedCheck" /></dd>
</dl>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hswbL/1

I've tried running it through a couple validators - HTML and Javascript - but can't find where the issue is.  Any help would be appreciated!

Also, I know I haven't included the multipart form property yet - but that shouldn't make a difference for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by moving the input line outside of the

tags, like so:

```
<dl>
<dt>
<label for="voidedCheck">Voided Check:</label>
</dt>
<input type="file" style="font-size:16px; height:25px;width:240px" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="voidedCheck" name="voidedCheck" />
</dl>
```